# Textarea's value is not changing by jquery using TinyMCE

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using tiny mce as editor in php. But it is not working.

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         tinymce.init({selector:'#album_description_input'});

          $('#create_picture_album_form').ajaxForm({

              beforeSubmit : function(){

              /*$('#album_description_input').html("Hello");*/      
              $('#album_description_input').html(tinymce.get('album_description_input').getContent());

              }
          });


    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="album_description_input" id="album_description_input"></textarea>
```

I am sure that the value of the `textarea` is not changing before submitting the form. I have tested the page by developer tool. Whenever i am adding `$("#album_description_input").html("Hello")` the submission of form is successful and data is pushed in the database. But if i add the line in js file commenting the next line it doesn't work. Why is that?

PHP:

```
$album_head = array(

                                    'base_url'                      => base_url(),
                                    'album_head_big_picture_path'   => $big_final_path,
                                    'album_head_small_picture_path' => $small_final_path,
                                    'album_title'                   => $_POST['album_title_text_input'],
                                    'album_project_type'            => $_POST['album_project_type_input'],
                                    'album_description'             => $_POST['album_description_input'],
                                    'status'                        => 'activated',
                                    'date_of_modification'          => date("d-M-Y"),
                                    'time_of_modification'          => date("h:m:s"),
                                    'user_of_modification'          => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                                    'user_ip'                       => $this->input->ip_address()
                                );
                                $album_head_id = $this->site_management_model->insert_album_head($album_head);
```

**NOTE :** I am using `action="upload.php"` .so no need of `tinyMCE.triggerSave();`

Comment: You have a `,` here `},`.

Comment: sorry i was just pasting important blocks. But it wasnot the problem @JohnBupit

Comment: Though there is no problem in php I am pasting it.

Comment: Your question title is misleading, then.

Comment: As long as i know `TinyMce` is used in two different way. Ajax submission : need to add `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` PHP Submission : need to add `$('#album_description_input').html(tinymce.get('album_description_input').getContent());`. as i am using php submission the jquery is not working. What can i do?

Comment: From your html, it would appear the editor starts out as empty, and this code to set the html is executed on page load.. so, where is the content supposed to come from?